# Корректно ли в свойство `HTMLInputElement.value` записывать не строку, а число? В какой момент происходит преобразование типа?

Tags: javascript

> value - string: Returns / Sets the current value of the control.

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement